# Some errors appeared during apply a practical example to Builder design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have written a code which applies the "Builder" design pattern but some errors appeared:

[image]

The code:

```
class Builder {
public:
    int m_suger;
    int m_cup;
    string m_flavour;

    Builder* sugar(int sugar) {
        this->m_suger = sugar;
        return this;
    }
    Builder* cup(int cup) {
        this->m_cup = cup;
        return this;
    }
    Builder* flavour(string flavour) {
        this->m_flavour = flavour;
        return this;
    }
    Tea* build() {
        return new Tea(this);
    }
};

class Tea {
public:
    int m_suger;
    int m_cup;
    string m_flavour;

    Tea(Builder* b) {
        m_suger = b->m_suger;
        m_cup = b->m_cup;
        m_flavour = b->m_flavour;
        cout << "Hot " << b->m_cup << " cup of tea is comming!, with " << b->m_flavour << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Tea* mintTea = new Builder()->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you not missing a forward declaration for `Tea`, to be placed before the `Builder` class declaration?

Comment: you should probably use references instead of using raw pointer and not deleting your new

Comment: @Bathsheba: When using a forward declaration for `Tea`, other errors appeared [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUfQF.jpg).

Comment: Oh yes, `return new Tea(this);` requires a *complete type* for `Tea`. I think it's time to start thinking about moving the implementation of your class member functions to a source file, where you can include the class definitions for `Tea` and `Builder1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the situation that the functions in `Builder` require `Tea` to be a complete class and the function in `Tea` requires `Builder` to be a complete class. But this is not a contradiction: `Builder` and `Tea` can both be complete classes before you start defining your functions.

```
class Tea; // Forward declaration is needed so Builder can mention Tea in its member function declarations.

class Builder {
public:
    int m_suger;
    int m_cup;
    string m_flavour;

    Builder* sugar(int sugar);
    Builder* cup(int cup);
    Builder* flavour(string flavour) ;
    Tea* build();
};

class Tea {
public:
    int m_suger;
    int m_cup;
    string m_flavour;

    Tea(Builder* b);
};
```

The classes are now complete and you can access all their members. Now you can go ahead and define their functions afterwards:

```
Builder* Builder::sugar(int sugar) {
    this->m_suger = sugar;
    return this;
}
Builder* Builder::cup(int cup) {
    this->m_cup = cup;
    return this;
}
Builder* Builder::flavour(string flavour) {
    this->m_flavour = flavour;
    return this;
}
Tea* Builder::build() {
    return new Tea(this);
}

Tea::Tea(Builder* b) {
    m_suger = b->m_suger;
    m_cup = b->m_cup;
    m_flavour = b->m_flavour;
    cout << "Hot " << b->m_cup << " cup of tea is comming!, with " << b->m_flavour << endl;
}
```

[Demo!](https://godbolt.org/g/kTcGgJ)

The first section of code would usually be the part that is placed in a header (`.h`) file so that other pieces of code `#include` that and work with your classes, whereas the second snippet would go into its own compilation unit (`.cpp`) because how the functions are implemented behind the scenes is generally of no concern/influence to other code.

*Note: The correct call in `main` would have to be:*

```
Tea* mintTea = (new Builder())->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build();
```

*Note the parantheses around `new Builder()`.*

Comment: I have separated the code so that each class in a separate file, but it still some errors appear [look Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jtps.jpg). Note: Line `31` is located in the main function.

Comment: Yes, I had to modify `main` in the demo, check it out. It has to be `(new Builder())->cup(2)/*...*/->build();` for the `new` to work as intended. I've added that as note to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I have an inquiry, why do you just put this part `new Builder()` inside Parentheses?

Comment: I cannot give you the "language lawyer" reasoning for it, but `new Builder()->build()` is not a valid expression, but `(new Builder())` is (and thus the chain of calls). This may have to do with the grammar that [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) has, but I don't know.